# Possible error not shown at SQLite manager

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table 'student' in which I have five attributes `{id,first,last,age,marks}.`

The following are the two tuples inserted.

```
1,Suresh,Kumar,35,95
2,ramesh,Kapoor,21,90
```

When I execute the query with mistake

```
select * from stdent where first='Suresh'
```

I get the alert message - no such table stdent.Very fair!

But when I execute the following query

```
select * from student where first='sachin'
```

I get no alerts or error message even though sachin is not present in any of the tuple.

What is the reason?

Comment: You are using `stdent` in the first query and `student` in the second one. These are two different names of tables .

Comment: I mean to say that, when the table names, query format is all correct and when I'm trying to search for a value which is not in database, why it is not giving any error?? Please read the question once again

Comment: DBMS returns empty rowset in last case, no reason to issue any warning/error messages. This is standard behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the query below is correct. No issues with the query itself. However, no tuple exists with first=sachin. Therefore, nothing is returned.

```
 select * from student where first='sachin'
```

If you try

```
 select * from student where first='Suresh'
```

then the query will successfully return 1 row, as a tuple with first=Suresh exists.

Comment: You mean to say that, SQL manager need not intimate me by any means that sachin is not in any of the tuples?

Comment: I don't use SQL manager, so I am not sure about it. I use PHPmyadmin which notifies me with "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."